# Is channels required to use socket with django? Is there any other alternative or way?

Tags: python, django, sockets, channel

I am using the django framework. I'll do the messaging part. I will do this with the socket. However, I always come across a channel library. Is there no other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without writing your own socket library, Channels is as close as you're going to get to official support. You could use Tornado (a different framework) for lower-level handling of simpler cases, but as far as Django goes, Channels is the normal pathway.

Is there a reason you didn't want to use Channels?

Comment: unfortunately I am constantly having incompatibility issues.I could not find it in the tutorial about channel 2.

Comment: For example, can't I write a separate chat application with node js and connect with django? For example, can't I create concurrent notifications? like notification when a post is created

Comment: If you want notifications when a post is created, you may be looking for Signals - not Channels. If you're going to use Node you might as well use that for the entire stack - I'm not sure how you'd split a Node / Django environment particularly effectively without a huge amount of work.